# Difference between the verbs "appropriate" and "expropriate"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

*Expropriate* has the following definitions [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/expropriate):

> 1. to deprive of possession or proprietary rights
> 2. to transfer (the property of another) to one's own possession

For example, in the following sentence:

> The Government's motion seeks to **expropriate** the company's private intellectual property to facilitate an investigation. (emphasis added)

At first I thought the difference between **appropriate** and **expropriate** was *who* the benefit was going to. In other words, you would appropriate property you had possession/ownership of, but if you were to use someone else's property, that would be an *expropriation*.

But *appropriate* is defined as [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appropriate):

> 1. to take exclusive possession of
> 2. to set apart for or assign to a particular purpose or use
> 3. to take or make use of without authority or right

That third definition seems to imply you can appropriate both property that belongs to you *or* property that doesn't belong to you. In the later case, the definition is the same as expropriate.

Can anyone sort out this mess?

Comment: The meanings can certainly overlap, to an extent. But I think the [relatively rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=appropriated%2Cexpropriated&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappropriated%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexpropriated%3B%2Cc0) ***expropriate*** is often a legal / governmental action, where the focus is on *depriving the current owner of his [legal right to] ownership*, whereas the far more common ***appropriate*** generally emphasizes ***taking** the thing itself*.

Comment: The connotation of *appropriate* is the transference ***to*** the new holder.  The connotation of *expropriate* is the transference ***from*** the old holder.

Answer (score 2):

***Expropriate*** is generally used to imply removal by a heavy-handed, but legal force, often by government.

***Appropriate*** merely means to take something over as one's own. Illegality is not usually implied, but it does carry a sense of firmly transferring something to oneself or another, or on the part of another person to themselves or another. But note from the examples how it is used to describe the actions of nature.

However ***misappropriate*** implies acquisition by illegal means - fraud or theft..

A few examples of the use of each of the three words, from the OED, should help explain.

***Expropriate***

> 1875   J. H. Bennet Winter & Spring Mediterranean (ed. 5) xiii. 480
>   The Government gives..a power to expropriate the owner of the land
>   required.
>
> 1881   Macmillan's Mag. 44 132   To expropriate the owners from their
>   estates must be a very bitter pill.
>
> 1881   Daily Tel. 14 Feb.   A corner of the garden..was ‘expropriated’
>   by Baron Haussman for the purpose of widening the Rue Lafayette.
>
> 1884   Contemp. Rev. Oct. 518   The State..expropriates private
>   property for public utility.

***Appropriate***

> 1876   E. Mellor Priesthood i. 15   The name ‘priest~hood’..was never
>   appropriated by apostles to themselves.
>
> 1785   W. Cowper Task v. 761   A liberty like his, who unimpeached Of
>   usurpation..Appropriates nature as his Father's work.
>
> 1871   J. Tyndall Fragm. Sci. II. vi. 83   The bud appropriates those
>   constituents..for which it has elective attraction.
>
> 1809   T. E. Tomlins Jacob's Law-dict. at Appropriation,   The
>   monasteries..appropriated as many benefices as they could by any means
>   obtain.>
>
> > 1801   J. Strutt Glig-gamena Angel-ðeod Introd. 7   These
> >     amusements..were appropriated to the season of Lent.
>
> 1839   H. Hallam Introd. Lit. Europe III. vii. 634   The subject
>   chosen is appropriated to the characteristic peculiarities of the
>   poet.

***Misappropriate***

> 1904   J. Conrad Nostromo ii. iii. 127,   I am not likely to
>   misappropriate the funds.
>
> 1952   W. Plomer Museum Pieces (1961) xxvi. 204   He had
>   misappropriated the funds entrusted to him.
>
> 1987   Melody Maker 8 Aug. 10   Disfiguring and misappropriating pop's
>   legacies.
>
> 1990   Times 2 Feb. 34/7   The purpose of the fraud was to enable
>   moneys to be ingathered and misappropriated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the ***[grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/appropriate-expropriate/)*** notes, appropriate and expropriate are often used interchangeably in reference to goverment appropriation of private property:

***To expropriate***:

> - is to deprive of possession, especially using eminent domain or judicial action. ***So expropriate is often interchangeable with appropriate where the latter involves depriving of possession, and both words are indeed commonly used in reference to government appropriation of private property and companies.***

As in :

> - *The Columbia City Council yesterday approved a measure to appropriate funds that could be used to provide bonuses to city employees. [Columbia Daily Tribune]*

***To appropriate***:

> - is (1) to take possession of for one’s own use, and (2) to set something apart for a specific use. To appropriate something is not necessarily to deprive another of possession; for example, an artist might appropriate another’s style, or one might appropriate a catchy archaic phrase from the 18th century. ***But appropriation does sometimes involve depriving of possession, such as when a government appropriates a private company. In its second sense, appropriate usually applies to government funds or other official resources given out for specified purposes. This use of the word is primarily American,***  but it’s not unheard of elsewhere.

Comment: appropriate funds;exproproriate property, whethere real property(chattels) or funds. The grammarist is confused. To appropriate is never to deprive another of their rightful possessions. At least, I've never seen it used like that.

Comment: Isn't the third def'n of appropriate exactly depriving someone of their rightful possessions? I quote: "to take or make use of without authority or right." How can you make use of without authority if you're not depriving someone of a right?